# How to load table data after submitting the form in react js php

Tags: php, html, reactjs

[form image | screenshot of my form and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AKhZ.jpg)

What i tried so far:

I have the form on the left side and Table data on the right side. After submitting the form I want to load the data immediately on the table.

I have `Insert` component and `ShowAll` component. I am importing the `ShowAll` component into the `Insert` component but **ShowAll component is not loading after form submit**

````
import Axios from 'Axios'
import ShowAll from './ShowAll';
class Insert extends React. Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name : '',
            email:'',
            city:'',
            country:'',
            job:'',
            output:''
        }
    }
    handleInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(this.state.name !== '' && this.state.email !== '' && this.state.city !== '' && this.state.job !== '' && this.state.country !== ''){

            axios.post('http://localhost/facebook/test.php',this.state)
            .then(res=>{
                this.setState({
                    output:res.data.success
                })
                this.setState({
                    name :'',email:'',city:'',country:'',job:''
                })
                // this.props.history.push("/");
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }else{
            //const errors = <span style="color:red">All fields are required</span>
            alert('All fields are required')
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {output} = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Insert Form {output}</h1>
                <form>
                    Name : <input name='name' value={this.state.name} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    Email : <input name='email' value={this.state.email} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    City : <input name='city' value={this.state.city} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    Country : <input name='country' value={this.state.country} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    Job : <input name='job' value={this.state.job} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    <input type='button' value="Submit" name='submit' onClick={(e)=>this.handleSubmit(e)}/>
                </form>
                <ShowAll/>
            </div>
        )        
    }
}
export default Insert;```

** This is my ShowAll component**

import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class ShowAll extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            contacts : [],
            lists : ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost/facebook/contacts.php')
        .then(res =>{
            this.setState({
                contacts : res.data.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {

        })
    }
    render(){
        if(this.state.contacts.length > 0){
            this.state.lists = this.state.contacts.map(contact => (
                <tr key={contact.id}>
                    <td>{contact.name}</td>
                    <td>{contact.email}</td>
                    <td>{contact.city}</td>
                    <td>{contact.country}</td>
                    <td>{contact.job}</td>
                    <td> <Link to={'/edit/'+contact.id}>Edit</Link> </td>
                    <td> <Link to={'/delete/'+contact.id}>Delete</Link> </td>
                </tr>
                ));
        }else{
            this.state.lists = <tr><td>No Records found</td></tr>
        }

        return(
            <>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Job</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.lists} 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </>
        )
    }
}
export default ShowAll```
````

Comment: Can you post code of `ShowAll` component.

Comment: You would be fetching data from endpoint in `ShowAll` component. Where is the logic written to fetch data(means in which lifecycle method)?

Comment: Added the `ShowAll` component code in down

Comment: I used componentDidMount lifecycle to fetch the data from API

Comment: Since you are fetching data from componentDidMount, Data will load only when ShowAll component  mounts first time. You need to perform this task of fetching updated data from componentDidUpdate

Comment: Can you give me an example for it? Anyway ,so, do I need to replace from componentDidMount to componentDidUpdate lifecycle? Is that right

Comment: componentDidUpdate won't be called first time when component mounts, so you need to keep same logic of fetching data in both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. I will share the code with you once I have access to my laptop.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. please share me the code. Thank you so much

Comment: @mukesh210  I got the solution. now it's working as expected.

Comment: I don't know the approach you took. So, answering my idea so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea would be to save timestamp(i.e. `recordGenerationTime`) in `Insert` component when any insert is made successfully. This `recordGenerationTime` would be passed to `ShowAll` component so that from `componentDidUpdate` `ShowAll` will compare previous timestamp with current timestamp and decides if API call have to be made or not.

Updated Components code would looks like below:

Insert Component:

```js
import Axios from 'Axios'
import ShowAll from './ShowAll';
class Insert extends React. Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name : '',
            email:'',
            city:'',
            country:'',
            job:'',
            output:'',
            recordGenerationTime: '',
        }
    }
    handleInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(this.state.name !== '' && this.state.email !== '' && this.state.city !== '' && this.state.job !== '' && this.state.country !== ''){

            axios.post('http://localhost/facebook/test.php',this.state)
            .then(res=>{
                this.setState({
                    output:res.data.success,
                    recordGenerationTime: new Date().getTime()
                })
                this.setState({
                    name :'',email:'',city:'',country:'',job:''
                })
                // this.props.history.push("/");
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }else{
            //const errors = <span style="color:red">All fields are required</span>
            alert('All fields are required')
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {output} = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Insert Form {output}</h1>
                <form>
                    Name : <input name='name' value={this.state.name} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    Email : <input name='email' value={this.state.email} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    City : <input name='city' value={this.state.city} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    Country : <input name='country' value={this.state.country} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    Job : <input name='job' value={this.state.job} onChange={(event)=>this.handleInput(event)} /><br/>
                    <input type='button' value="Submit" name='submit' onClick={(e)=>this.handleSubmit(e)}/>
                </form>
                <ShowAll 
                  recordGenerationTime={this.state.recordGenerationTime} />
            </div>
        )        
    }
}
export default Insert;
```

ShowAll Component:

```js
import React from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    class ShowAll extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {
                contacts : [],
                lists : ''
            }
        }
        componentDidMount(){
            this.fetchContacts();
        }
        
        componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
          if(prevProps.recordGenerationTime !== this.props.recordGenerationTime && this.props.recordGenerationTime) {
            this.fetchContacts();
          }
        }
        
        fetchContacts = () => {
          axios.get('http://localhost/facebook/contacts.php')
            .then(res =>{
                this.setState({
                    contacts : res.data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {

            })
        }
        
        render(){
            if(this.state.contacts.length > 0){
                this.state.lists = this.state.contacts.map(contact => (
                    <tr key={contact.id}>
                        <td>{contact.name}</td>
                        <td>{contact.email}</td>
                        <td>{contact.city}</td>
                        <td>{contact.country}</td>
                        <td>{contact.job}</td>
                        <td> <Link to={'/edit/'+contact.id}>Edit</Link> </td>
                        <td> <Link to={'/delete/'+contact.id}>Delete</Link> </td>
                    </tr>
                    ));
            }else{
                this.state.lists = <tr><td>No Records found</td></tr>
            }

            return(
                <>
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>Job</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {this.state.lists} 
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </>
            )
        }
    }
    export default ShowAll
```